# Way to import small parts of semantic ui?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

I'd like to use specific modules from `semantic-ui` , https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky.html

Suppose I also use other frameworks mainly (such as bootstrap). 
I wouldn't want to include the whole `semantic-ui` just for the one module I need.

Is there a way to import (include..) only the specific modules I need from semantic-ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply include `.css` file and `.js` (if it's available) file of the specific component. Here is an example with a CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/components/sticky.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/components/sticky.js" ></script>
```

You can find all the components in `dist/components/` [folder](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/dist/components), for more information about semantic-ui installation see   [Semantic-UI on GitHub](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI)