# Use semantic-ui behaviors in angular2

Tags: angular, semantic-ui, angular-components

I'm going to use some [semantic-ui behaviors](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/visibility.html) on angular2 components.

I tried some integrations like [ng2-semantic-ui](https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui) but unfortunately, it doesn't support "Visibility behaviors" at this moment and I should implement it manually, but as we already know we can't use `<script>` tag on angular templates, so I can't call semantic-ui functions manually.

Have you any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Simply include Semantic-UI in `index.html` file *(this will make all the modules working for all your templates )* :

*PS: `<script>` tag works in `index.html` file.*

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.min.js"></script>
<!--or -->
    <script src="relaive_path_to/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

In `your.component.ts` file add this:`declare var $: any;` next to the importing section , then initialize Visibility behavior) in `ngAfterViewInit(){}` like the following :

[[DEMO]](http://plnkr.co/edit/qFXX5r?p=preview) *(re-run it to see Lazy Loading Images with visibility behavior)*

**component.ts**

```
import {Component,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'demo.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

    ngAfterViewInit(){

$('.demo.items .image img')
  .visibility({
    type       : 'image',
    transition : 'fade in',
    duration   : 1000
  })
;
    }
}
```

If you want only use a specific module see [Way to import small parts of Semantic-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297987/way-to-import-small-parts-of-semantic-ui/45310578#45310578).

Comment: got error:  $('element').visibility is not a function, also included semantic and jquery files

Comment: did  you place your code under importing tag ? `<script src="..."></script>`

Comment: answer updated and demo added, if the problem persist , please fork the demo , add your code ,then comment it here

Comment: My code is exactly the same, except that I use webpack and cli instead of SystemJs config.I will fork my code as soon as possible.